# jmeter-5.4.1 html report generation failed

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

while generating html report through jmeter getting following error message.
note[using **jmeter version 5.4.1**]

```
Generating report
An error occurred: Data exporter "html" is unable to export data.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Data exporter "html" is unable to export data` message unfortunately doesn't contain either root cause of the issue or at least a clue.

You need to take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should contain way more information regarding the failure.

The most common reasons are:

- Lack of JVM Heap space
- Impossibility to write to the destination folder (lack of permissions, disk full, etc.)
- Issues with .jtl results file (i.e. you ran your test on another JMeter instance having different [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config))

Also be informed that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.